# Control Signal Raspbery Pi

Tags: c, dc-motor, signal

I have a project to generate DCC signal so it needs to be used bts7960 to control the signal and connected to Raspberry Pi 3B. But, unfortunately the signal wave is not like digital signal perfectly. There something cutting the signal, so the output only halfwave but in digital signal (I insert the picture below).
So anyone have solution to make the signal become digital signal perfectly?
[image]

Here the wiring I did it:

- VCC ---> 5V raspberry pi
- GND ---> GND raspberry pi
- R_IS and L_IS ---> not connected
- R_EN and L_EN ---> 5V raspberry pi
- RPWM ---> GPIO 13 raspberry pi
- LPWM ---> GPIO 12 raspberry pi
- B+ and B- ---> adaptor 16V
- M+ and M- ---> oscilloscope (soon as DCC signal)

The signal should be like this:

[image: The signal should be]

I also insert my code:

```
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PIN_DIR 12
#define PIN_PWM 13

const int BIT_TIMINGS[2] = {100, 58}; // timing for 0 & 1 bit

struct Packet {
    unsigned char address[8];
    unsigned char command[8];
    unsigned char EOR[8];
};

void EOR(struct Packet *train) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        train->EOR[i] = train->address[i] ^ train->command[i];
    }
}

void output_bit(unsigned char bit_val, unsigned char pin) {
    gpioWrite(pin, 1);
    gpioDelay(BIT_TIMINGS[bit_val]); // Delay in microseconds
    gpioWrite(pin, 0);
    gpioDelay(BIT_TIMINGS[bit_val]);
}

void go_straight(struct Packet *train) {
    int i;
    // Send packet preamble (12 ones and a zero)
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        output_bit(1, PIN_PWM);
    }
    output_bit(0, PIN_PWM);
    // Send address byte
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        output_bit(train->address[i], PIN_DIR);
    }
    output_bit(0, PIN_DIR);
    // Send instruction byte
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        output_bit(train->command[i], PIN_DIR);
    }
    output_bit(0, PIN_DIR);
    // Send error detection byte
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        output_bit(train->EOR[i], PIN_DIR);
    }
    output_bit(1, PIN_DIR);
}

void idle_packet(unsigned char how_many) {
    int i, k;
    for (k = 0; k < how_many; k++) { // how many idle packets to send
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) { // preamble bits
            output_bit(1, PIN_PWM);
        }
        output_bit(0, PIN_PWM);

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // address bits
            output_bit(1, PIN_DIR);
        }
        output_bit(0, PIN_DIR);

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // command bits
            output_bit(0, PIN_DIR);
        }
        output_bit(0, PIN_DIR);

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // exclusive OR bits
            output_bit(1, PIN_DIR);
        }
        output_bit(1, PIN_DIR);
    }
}

int main() {
    if (gpioInitialise() < 0) {
        return 1; // pigpio initialization failed
    }

    struct Packet forwardTrain = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, // address for forward direction
        {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // command for forward direction and full speed
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  // error check
    };

    gpioSetMode(PIN_DIR, PI_OUTPUT);
    gpioSetMode(PIN_PWM, PI_OUTPUT);

    gpioWrite(PIN_DIR, 1);
    gpioWrite(PIN_PWM, 1);
    gpioHardwarePWM(PIN_PWM, 8670, 750000);
    gpioHardwarePWM(PIN_DIR, 5000, 750000);

    EOR(&forwardTrain);

    idle_packet(100); // transmit 100 idle packets during initialization


    while (1) {
        go_straight(&forwardTrain);
        idle_packet(2);
    }

    gpioTerminate(); // Terminate pigpio
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: what's  wrong with the signal? ... what should it look like?

Comment: @Milliways I'm sorry. I'm not meaning to delete, I'm only want to make this question clearly, so this rewrite again

Comment: @jsotola Okay thank you. I have update the question, I insert the picture should be. Do you have any idea?

Comment: which GPIO pin are you measuring the signal? ... how are you measuring the signal, how is oscilloscope probe connected?